# Why is this array not working?

Tags: templates, array, the-content

So first I am trying to get all pictures from content to take first picture from content and set it as features image if such is not set.
I found part of thi online, it seems that this makes loop somehow (i do not get it how actually)

```
array(1) {  
    [0]=>
    array(4) {
    [0]=>    string(273) "whole image tag with alt"
    [1]=>    string(234) "whole image tag with alt"
    [2]=>    string(202) "whole image tag with alt"
    [3]=>    string(236) "whole image tag with alt"
  }
}
```

So ...  when i uncomment print_r($result); i do get an array that looks like this above. How to access first image tag? Maybe even access src or alt part of that tag? I tried to

echo $result[0];

but i got nothing. Why count is presenting 1 as answer and not 4?

```
        global $wp_query;
        $post = $wp_query->post;
        $page_id = $post->ID; // page ID
        $page_object = get_page( $page_id ); // page stuff
        //$author_id = $post->post_author; // author ID
        //$author_name = get_the_author_meta( 'display_name', $author_id);
        $page_content = $page_object->post_content;


        //first check all img tags in text              
        preg_match_all('/<img[^>]+>/i',$page_content, $result); 

        print_r($result);


        echo count($result);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your array is actually two dimensional.  It's  in two levels: an array containing an array of four strings.

Try `echo $result[0][0];`

Comment: yes true. That surely solved problem. To not opening new question, how to count how many array elements are in each dimension?

Comment: You can use echo count($result, COUNT_RECURSIVE); to get a total. An array of values probably wouldn't be so useful. count( $result[0] ) will tell you how many results you actually have in your case.

Comment: Thank you. this count( $result[0] ) i could not find anywhere and i knew there was some trick.

Comment: No problem. Glad to help.